# Matlab's arrayfun for uniform output of class objects

Tags: oop, class, matlab

I need to build an array of objects of class `ID` using arrayfun:

```
% ID.m
classdef ID < handle
    properties
        id
    end
    methods
        function obj = ID(id)
            obj.id = id;
        end
    end
end
```

But get an error:

```
>> ids = 1:5;
>> s = arrayfun(@(id) ID(id), ids) 
??? Error using ==> arrayfun
ID output type is not currently implemented.
```

I can build it alternatively in a loop:

```
s = [];
for k = 1 : length(ids)
    s = cat(1, s, ID(ids(k)));
end
```

but what is wrong with this usage of arrayfun?

Edit (clarification of the question): The question is not how to workaround the problem (there are several solutions), but why the simple syntax `s = arrayfun(@(id) ID(id), ids);` doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking `arrayfun` to do something it isn't built to do.

[The output from `arrayfun` must be](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arrayfun.html):

> scalar values (numeric, logical, character, or structure) or cell
>   arrays.

Objects don't count as any of the scalar types, which is why the "workarounds" all involve using a cell array as the output.  One thing to try is using `cell2mat` to convert the output to your desired form; it can be done in one line.  (I haven't tested it though.)

```
s = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(id) ID(id), ids,'UniformOutput',false));
```

Comment: actually CELL2MAT will fail with the error `Cannot support cell arrays containing cell arrays or objects.`

Comment: @Amro Ah, interesting. Thanks for pointing that out, like I said I hadn't tested it. Is there a way to get handles to the objects into a vector?

Comment: you can create object arrays (I posted an answer), just not with ARRAYFUN. In fact ARRAYFUN can *iterate* over array of objects (as input), just not return them as output (must return scalars of cells as you pointed out). You can also do it as @robince showed

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the easiest is to use cellfun, or force arrayfun to return a cell array by setting the `'UniformOutput'` option. Then you can convert this cell array to an array of obects (same as using cat above).

```
s = arrayfun(@(x) ID(x), ids, 'UniformOutput', false);
s = [s{:}];
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems as a patch, like the loop method. My question was why `arrayfun(@(id) ID(id), ids)` doesn't work. Is it a Matlab's bug, or wrong usage?

Comment: as I sometimes miss the python functionality to endlessly extend commands, and frequently use your cell to array construction I often declare an anonymous function to do it in one go: `dealcell = @(x)x{:};`, which can then be used like `s = [dealcell(arrayfun(...))];`

Comment: You need `s = reshape(s, size(ids))` to make that truly match `arrayfun`

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would create an [array of objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_oop/brd4btr.html):

```
s = ID.empty(0,5);
for i=5:-1:1
    s(i) = ID(i);
end
```

It is always a good idea to provide a "default constructor" with no arguments, or at least use default values:

```
classdef ID < handle
    properties
        id
    end
    methods
        function obj = ID(id)
            if nargin<1, id = 0; end
            obj.id = id;
        end
    end
end
```